# How to use dom-bind within test-fixture?

Tags: polymer, web-component, web-component-tester

How can I use `<template is="dom-bind">` within [`<test-fixture>`](https://github.com/Polymer/test-fixture) with [web-components-tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester)?

I have tried to use it Polymer 0.8 `x-template` way:

```
<test-fixture id="dom-bind-fixture">
    <template is="dom-bind">
        <h1>{{greeting}}</h2>
    </template>
</test-fixture>
<script>
    // ...
   var bound = fixture('dom-bind-fixture', {greeting: 'ohai thurr'});
</script>
```

which naturally fails, as `dom-bind` does not have `stamp` method.

Then, I tried just stamping it out of native `<template>` element:

```
<test-fixture id="dom-bind-fixture">
    <template>
        <h1>outside dom-bind</h1>
        <template is="dom-bind">
            <h2>inside dom-bind</h2>
        </template>
    </template>
</test-fixture>
```

But in non-Chrome browsers this one stamps only `outside dom-bind`.

Is there a way to make it work, or is it just a blocking bug in web-components-tester/test-fixture/dom-bind?

Comment: For reference, @tomalec created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Polymer/test-fixture/issues/17) to track this.

Answer (score 2):

Use dom-template, ie:

```
<test-fixture id="dom-bind-fixture">
    <template is="dom-template">
        <h1>{{greeting}}</h2>
    </template>
</test-fixture>
<script>
    // ...
   var bound = fixture('dom-bind-fixture', {greeting: 'ohai thurr'});
</script>
```